# How would I use JTag to diagnose an ATSAM3x8E processor?

Tags: usb, cortex-m, jtag

I have never used jtag before, and am still learning about machine language.

I have a 3D printer using a an arm cortex m3 based processor.  After sitting for a while it nolonger will even register on my computer via usb ports.  I erased the memory on the chip and it still doesn't show up as a com port on my pc like it used to.

I'm beginning to think I fried the chip with static electricity or something.  There is a jtag connector on the board.  How exactly can I usethe JTag connector to test the chip for damage?  There isn't much else on the board other than the chip.  Any other chips are drivers for stepper motors and such.  And the usb appears to go directly to the cpu, but don't take my word on that.

Comment: If you erased the flash memory of the microcontroller responsible for USB communication its is pretty natural, that USB communication with you PC is no longer working. You have erased the communication stack.

Answer (score 0):

For testing your chip via JTAG (or SWD) you should use a JTAG debugger also known as "In-Circuit Debugger" or also "In-Circuit Emulator". You can get some below 50$ or above 2000$.

However the firmware of the chip might block JTAG access e.g. unless you erase the flash. But since you did this anyway this shouldn't be a stopper.